# html5 maxlength not working in samsung s4

Tags: javascript, samsung-mobile, maxlength

The below code is not working Samsung Galaxy S4. I am trying to restrict maxlength(50). 
Anyone know of a javascript/jquery fix for the Samsung S4?.

```
enter code here

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/SAMSUNG GALAXY S4/i)) {
$('input[type="text"]').attr("maxlength", 50);
$('input[type="text"]').bind("change keyup", function() {
maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
if ($(this).val().length > maxlength) {
$(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, maxlength));
}              
});
}
```

Comment: what if it doesnt work in some more other devices?

Comment: Add a console.log inside the `if` to ensure your u/a detection works as you expect